# Qual a diferença de utilizar return e print nesta função recursiva que calcula a soma de números?

Tags: python, funções, recursão

Fiz uma função simples em Python para me dar a soma dos números de n até 0:

```
def retorna(n, zero, soma):
    if n <= zero:
        soma += n
        return soma
        retorna(n+1, zero, soma)
ret = retorna(1, 5, 0)
print(ret)
```

O resultado da função, como está é 1. Mas se eu colocar `print (soma)` no lugar de `return soma` (e chamar a função sem `print`), ela me dá:

```
1, 3, 6, 10, 15.
```

Por que isso acontece? Eu queria conseguir exibir apenas o último resultado, 15, no caso.

Podem me ajudar e me dar mais algum exemplo para eu entender?

Comment: O objetivo é praticar a recursividade ? Porque isto seria muito mais facil e faria muito mais sentido de forma iterativa.

Comment: Quase, o objetivo é aprender recursividade.

Comment: @IagoPaschoal Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro: este código funciona melhor iterativamente e não recursiva. Deixe para aprender recursão com problemas que precisam ser recursivos e aprenda melhor.

Um erro básico é que não está retornando o resultado da recursão, está só chamando a função e jogando fora seu resultado. E ainda está fazendo isso condicionalmente já que está dentro do `if`, não pode, ele deve executar todas as vezes, exceto a última.

O código poderia ter nome de variável mais significativo para saber do que se trata. A soma de `n` parece uma linha sem sentido ali, deveria ter a soma na função recursiva.

Exceto na última vez o retorno deve ser sempre o próprio resultado da função, toda recursão é assim.

```
def retorna(valor, limite, soma):
    if valor > limite:
        return soma
    return retorna(valor + 1, limite, soma + valor)
print(retorna(1, 5, 0))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wXyGMe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cswatphs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/RecursiveSum.py).

Comment: Obrigado. 
Mais uma coisa, se puder... Não entendi o critério de parada. Por que ele não fica em looping infinito? já que está para sempre retornar o "retorna(valor + 1, limite, soma + valor" ???

Comment: @IagoPaschoal você não viu que tem um `if`? Ali define a parada. Leu a parte `Exceto na última vez`?

Comment: Vi o if. Ele não sai do if e depois cai no "return retorna(valor........)"???

Comment: @IagoPaschoal você entende o que é um `if`? E o que é um `return`?

Comment: Até o momento, achava que sim.
O if faz parte da estrutura condicional. Se uma comparação depois do if for verdadeira, então o que está aninhado dentro do if é executado. Caso contrŕtio, o que está aninhado dentro do if não é executado.

O return retorna algum valor para a função. (mas creio não estar ainda muito claro o conceito de return na minha cabeça).

A pergunta continua... e se puder recomendar algo sobre o return, agradeço.

Comment: É, o `return` encerra a função e nada mais é executado nela.

Comment: Uou, agora entendi. O return além de retornar um valor, funciona como break. Só mais uma coisa. Qual é a diferença entre chamar a função com ""return retorna(valor + 1, limite, soma + valor)"" ou sem o return, apenas assim ""retorna(valor + 1, limite, soma + valor)""?

Comment: EU ach oque você precisa aprender de maneira estruturada, tem um monte de pequenos detalhes que fazem toda diferença. Aprender por demanda não costuma dar certo, cria a ilusão que está aprendendo. Programar é entender tudo o que está acontecendo, não ter uma visão por cima. A primeira estão retornando o valor da função chamada, a segunda não está.

Comment: Valeu. E por onde eu aprendo a maneira estruturada?

Comment: Livros e cursos de primeira linha.

Answer (score 2):

Se a função deve retornar a soma de um conjunto de inteiros, podemos definir matematicamente o problema. Consideremos que o intervalo seja definido por `a` e `b`: `[a, b]`, sendo `b` maior ou igual a `a`. Assim, temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta expressão pode ser expandida como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E é trivial perceber que pode ser reescrita como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que é nada mais que a forma recursiva da função de soma. Mas isso não pode ser infinito, caso contrário seu programa irá rodar eternamente. Precisamos de uma situação em que a escrita recursiva possa ser simplificada, gerando o que chamamos de condição de parada.

Para este exemplo, podemos analisar a situação quando o intervalo `[a, b]` chega no caso particular em que `a` é igual a `b`, ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto é, quando `a = b`, sabemos que a soma será apenas `b`.

Assim, podemos definir a nossa função `somar`, que recebe os valores `a` e `b`:

```
def somar(a, b):
    return a + somar(a+1, b) if a < b else b
```

Assim, como esperado, ao fazermos `somar(1, 5)` teremos o resultado 15.